# Multiply elements in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

Hi, I have an array :    `int [] num = new int[6]{1,2,2,1,1,2};`

I want to multiply the value at element 0 with every other value, I then want to multiply the value at element 1 with the values at elements 2 through to the last element. Then multiply the value at element 2 with the values from 3 through to the end, and so on until I have iterated through the whole array.

My efforts thus far seem clumsy and verbose, so I was wondering if anyone could show me an elegant way of achieving my aim.

Many thanks.

Comment: what do the "clumsy and verbose" attempts look like ? you should post them.

Comment: *Clumsy and verbose* efforts provide for fun reading :) Please do post something, and we'll help you make it elegant.

Comment: It's important to know that the products can get VERY big and you might lose data consistency with your int array. Is this problem possible in your scenario?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go through the array backwards and do it in one pass and not repeat operations.

```
 for (int i = num.Length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
 {
     num[i] *= num[i + 1];
 }
```

Gives `8,8,4,2,2,2`

Answer (score 2):

```
Enumerable.Range(0,num.Length)
    .Select(i => num.Skip(i).Aggregate(1, (a, b) => a * b))
```

Gives a sequence 8, 8, 4, 2, 2, 2. Is this what you meant?

Comment: This is very slow O(n^2). However, if there were a "fold-back" method (as `List.foldBack`) available then it could be done pretty and fast.

Comment: Yep. Ray got my upvote! OTOH I wouldn't expect an aggregate multiplication to be carried out on too many items as it would become easy to overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.Length; i++)
{
    // Multiply element i
    for (int j = i+1; j < num.Length; j++)
    {
       num[i] *= num[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int[] num = new int[6] { 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2 };

```
        int i = 0;

        while (i < num.Length)

        {
            for (int j = i; j < num.Length;j++)

            {

                if((j+1)<num.Length)

                num[i] = num[i] + num[j + 1];

            }

            Console.WriteLine(num[i]);

            i++;

        }
```

Comment: You realise that adds not multiples? And once fixed is functionally identical to another answer?